# How to show multiple lines in google-chart linr-graph

Tags: polymer

I have polymer code like this:

```
<google-chart type='line' options='{"title": "Sales Statistics, Billions", "vAxis": {"minValue" : 0, "maxValue": 40}, "curveType": "function"}' rows='[["Monday", 31], ["Tuesday", 28], ["Wednesday", 31], ["thursday", 22], ["friday", 11]]' cols='[{"label":"Weeks", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]'></google-chart>
```

The code works fine. But, I don't know how to show multiple lines of data. 
That means my output is [image]

I want like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem. Add another element to `cols` array as

```
cols='[{"label":"Weeks", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]'
```

And add another element to array of the rows, which acts as co-ordinates for another line in the graph as

```
rows='[["Monday", 31, 11], ["Tuesday", 28, 22], ["Wednesday", 31, 33], ["thursday", 22, 44], ["friday", 11, 44]]'
```

Thanks.